# Ponteiros e tipo de dados oculto em C

Tags: c

EDIT: Vou deixar os códigos logo abaixo em texto mesmo.

Boa noite. Por favor vejam a imagem em anexo.

Ele é a implementação de uma função cujo protótipo está definido num outro arquivo de nome "pilha.h". Do jeito que está, funciona perfeitamente.

Porém, se eu apagar a linha 11 e modificar a linha 5 para **typedef struct { .... } pilha;** eu tenho um erro de compilação:

> pilha.c: In function ‘criaPilha’:
>
> pilha.c:15:6: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type ‘struct
>   pilha’
>
> ```
>  p->v = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char));
>   ^~
> ```

Alguém poderia me ajudar a entender esse erro?

Desde já, obrigado!

[image: Arquivo "pilha.c"]

--------------- pilha.h -----------------

```
typedef struct pilha *Pilha;

Pilha criaPilha(int tamanho);

int pilhaCheia(Pilha p);

int pilhaVazia(Pilha p);

void empilha(Pilha p, char elemento);

char desempilha(Pilha p);

int topo(Pilha p);

char eleTopo(Pilha p);
```

---

----------- pilha.c -----------

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "pilha.h"

struct pilha {
    char *v;
    int topo;
    int tamanho;
};

typedef struct pilha pilha;

Pilha criaPilha(int tamanho) {
    Pilha p = malloc(sizeof(pilha));
    p->v = malloc(tamanho * sizeof(char));
    p->topo = 0;
    p->tamanho = tamanho;

    return p;
}

int pilhaCheia(Pilha p) {
    if (p->topo > p->tamanho)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

int pilhaVazia(Pilha p) {
    if (p->topo == 0)
        return 1;
    return 0;
}

void empilha(Pilha p, char elemento) {
    if (!pilhaCheia(p)) {
        p->topo++;
        p->v[p->topo] = elemento;
    }
    else
        printf("Pilha cheia!\n");
}

char desempilha(Pilha p) {
    if (!pilhaVazia(p)) {
        p->topo--;
        return p->v[p->topo + 1];
    }
    else
        return '\0';
}

int topo(Pilha p) {
    return p->topo;
}

char eleTopo(Pilha p) {
    return p->v[p->topo];
}
```

Comment: Coloque o código em texto pra facilitar pra gente, e o `.h`.

Comment: Deixei os códigos no edit do post.

Comment: Eu ia copiar e colar seu código para alterar e fazer uma resposta, mas como imagem fica difícil.

Comment: Oi, @VictorStafusa. Eu editei o post e deixei os códigos nos comentários.

Answer (score 1):

```
typedef struct Pilha {
    char *v;
    int topo;
    int tamanho;
} Pilha;

Pilha *criaPilha(int tamanho) {
    Pilha *p = (Pilha *) malloc(sizeof(Pilha));
    p->v = (char *) malloc(tamanho);
    p->topo = 0;
    p->tamanho = tamanho;
    return p;
}
```

Há algumas coisas aqui a serem observadas:

1. Você não deve confundir `pilha` com `Pilha`. Lembre-se que C diferencia maiúsculas de minúsculas. Ter `Pilha` e `pilha` como coisas diferentes é pedir para fazer lambança.
2. A função `malloc` sempre retorna um ponteiro. Portanto, não se esqueça do `*` no ponteiro.
3. Observe a sintaxe estranha do `typedef`. Ela diz que o apelido dado para `struct Pilha {...}` é `Pilha`.
4. Colocar *casts* no `malloc` é uma boa ideia. O motivo disso é que há alguns problemas de interoperabilidade entre C e C++ se você não fizer isso.
5. O padrão da linguagem C diz que `sizeof(char)` sempre é 1, independente da plataforma que for. Logo, não precisa multiplicar por `sizeof(char)` dentro do `malloc`.
6. Ocultar que um tipo de dados é um ponteiro por meio de um `typedef` é outra forma de pedir para fazer lambança.
7. No arquivo de cabeçalho `pilha.h`, você usaria apenas `typedef struct Pilha Pilha;`, enquanto colocaria o `struct` completo no `pilha.c`.

Comment: Oi, Victor. Então:


#1. O Pilha (maiúsculo) é um tipo de dados que o cliente usaria, enquanto que o pilha (minúsculo) é apenas a implementação das funções que não ficariam visíveis para o cliente. Por tanto, foi deixado assim propositalmente.


#2. No arquivo pilha.h foi há uma linha "typedef struct pilha *Pilha", ou seja, quando eu invocar Pilha automaticamente estou me referindo ao ponteiro para struct pilha, por isso não usei *.


#3. Idem #1 e #2


#4. Informação interessante!


#5. Muito bem notado! Passei isso desapercebido kk


Obrigado pelos comentários e informações

Comment: @LucasLopes Editei a resposta para endereçar esses pontos que você levantou.

Comment: Entendi. Realmente o #6 é algo que gera confusão. Apenas o usei para tentar "entender como funciona". Pelo visto não é nem de longe uma boa prática de programação. 

Obrigado novamente!

Comment: Tanto o #3 como o #4 são bem comuns de se usar em C. Em relação ao `malloc` não levar *cast* é porque a sintaxe fica bem menos verbosa e mais simples de manter valida se alterar o tipo do ponteiro, entre outras coisas, como é debatido [neste post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). Para além disso é bem improvável que se queira compilar mallocs em c++ uma vez que c++ tem formas bem melhores de declarar memória e que são validadas em relação ao tipo, como o operador `new`.

Comment: @Isac Sei que usar `malloc` em C++ não é considerado uma das melhores práticas, mas já vi acontecer algumas vezes mesmo sem haver um bloco `extern "C" {...}`, e já vi perguntas aqui no SOpt onde isso gerou confusão. Inclusive, [`new` não é considerado mais boa prática em C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6500313/540552). Quanto ao #3, eu digo que a sintaxe é estranha porque para iniciantes parece bem confusa (e convenhamos, seria mais intuitivo ter o apelido antes do tipo que está sendo apelidado ao invés de depois).